# How to subdivide faces with a half edge DS?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, geometry

Assume we have a mesh represented as a half edge datastructure.

We want to subdivide faces without introducing unnecessary vertices (i.e the new number of vertices must be exactly V + E where V is the old number of vertices and E is the old number of edges).

This is what a single subdivided triangle looks like:
[image]

If I naively try to iterate over every edge and reconnect faces I get the following sequence
[image]
[image]
[image]

Clearly this is wrong.

If instead I iterate over the faces I get the following pattern:

[image]

This is happening because at every step I am trying to to:

- Focus on only one simplex at a time,
- Maintain the connectivity information of the mesh in a valid state (every edge has <2 faces, vertices only exist at the end of edges, faces only have 3 Half edges...), like for example, I am avoiding getting into this state:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one answered so I will. The solution is to do the subdivision in 2 passes, first generating new triangles as I showed in the question.

Then on the second pass you flip them.

[image]

As described there:
https://github.com/cmu462/Scotty3D/wiki/Loop-Subdivision